# ASP.NET Session Management - User Decides Cookies Or HttpSessionState

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies, session-state

I am working on a small web application right now and part of the requirements is to allow the user to pick how their session will be managed: with either cookies or HttpSessionState. I have researched how to use cookies (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31914/Beginner-s-Guide-To-ASP-NET-Cookies) and Sessions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx). I will be using non-persistent cookies.

The application will collect some data about the user (name, age, school) and take this session data and display messages on another page depending on the data that the user entered.

The thing I am having problems with is how to deal with how the user will pick the management. That information is also part of the session! The selection will be checked on every page on the web application.

I have researched globals (http://www.dotnetperls.com/global-variables-aspnet) but that is not a good method because it can be shared among different users which is not what I want! Correct me if I am wrong. How can I store this data temporarily through the session without actually using a session or a cookie?

Is it even possible to do this with cookies and sessions being mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the day, you should save it somewhere. This option if it is not persistent, as it may be asked/changed by every time user visits the web site, the easiest way is to save it in a hidden html field. As user submits the forms, the value will be passed to the next page if you are using html forms. Or you can  retrieve the value and send it manually in asp.net (e.g. Transfer).

You may use ViewState (not recommended) as well. If the information should be persister for future, try using User Profiles in ASP.net and save it as a custom field in database. This one is really cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks! I don't need a database at this point so I suppose the hidden html field is the best option right now. It just seems a little strange to have to pass it through about 5 pages that way... but the requirement itself is also a little strange! :)